# How to convert string into SCC character

Tags: ruby

I want to export some strings in my application into CSS format. For example,

```
[00:01:14.20] {RU2}{RU2}{CR}{CR}{1500}{1500}YOUR PLACE TO LEARN AND TALK
```

to:

```
00:01:14:20 9425 9425 94ad 94ad 9470 9470 d94f d552 20d0 4cc1 4345 2054 4f20 4c45 c152 ce20 c1ce c420 54c1 4ccb
```

Is there any gem that takes care of this? Or, do I need to create my own logic?

Comment: Your expected output does not look like CSS format.

Answer (score 1):

The Scenarist Closed Captions format tools have no bindings for ruby, AFAIK. The possible solution would be to download the [tools](http://www.theneitherworld.com/mcpoodle/SCC_TOOLS/SCC_TOOLS.ZIP) from the [author’s site](http://www.theneitherworld.com/mcpoodle/SCC_TOOLS/DOCS/SCC_TOOLS.HTML), extract the perl scripts from `SOURCE` folder inside zip archive, bundle these perl scripts with your project and call these scripts as linux system utilities via `%x||`.

I know no better alternative to implementing the logic yourself / porting these perls to ruby.